# Is there an easy way to calculate the probability?

Tags: probability

I wonder whether there is a way to calculate the probability of this problem. 
Mr Smith is a door-to-door salesman.For the last 30 days, he has been knocking at my door randomly trying to sell me widgets. He came on the 1st, 3rd, 4th, 11th, 15th, 17th, 19th, 23rd, and 28th.
What's the probability that he will come knocking at my door on the 31st day of the month? The day after the 31st?

Comment: If it was my door and he also came on the 31st, the probability of him coming back would be $0$.

Comment: Did you check if the month under consideration actually has $31$ days?

Answer (score 2):

To calculate probabilities you need a **model**. A model would be some mathematical description of Mr. Smith's behavior, such as

*"Mr. Smith comes every day with probability $\frac{1}{3}$"*

or

*"If he hadn't come for more than three days, Mr. Smith will come with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, otherwise he will come with probability $\frac{1}{5}$"*

or even more complex schemes (*"If he came a prime number of times this week, and it's an odd day of the month, he will come with probability $\frac{1}{4}$, ...."*) as long as they provide a general description that you assume to be true in the future.

What you have are **observations**, that is, records of past behavior. If you want to predict the probability of future events, you must make these observations into a model. However, note that these observations fit many models; for example:

(1) *"Mr. Smith comes on the 1st, 3rd, 4th, 11th, 15th, 17th, 19th, 23rd and 28th of each month and never on any other day"*

(2) *"Mr. Smith comes every day with probability $\frac{1}{3}$"*

(3) *"Mr. Smith comes every day with probability $\frac{1}{1000}$"*

(4) *"Mr. Smith comes every day with probability $\frac{999}{1000}$"*

(5) *"Mr. Smith comes on every even day with probability $\frac{1}{10}$ and on every odd day with probability $\frac{1}{5}$"*

Are all consistent with the observations. (Note that some models, such as *"Mr. Smith never comes"* or *"Mr. Smith comes every day"*) are not consistent with the observations.

The likelihood of the observations given any specific model can be computed - for example, the observations are much more likely given 
(2) than given 
(3) - so in a sense you can say that (2) is a "better model" than (3).

Note, however, that the results fit perfectly (with probability $1$) given (1), but you still wouldn't intuitively say that this is a better model, because it seems more unlikely to begin with.

What we usually do to narrow this problem is assume that the model comes from a specific family of models, such as *"Mr. Smith comes every day with probability $p$ independently of other days"*. Note that this model is actually an infinite set of models containing (2), (3), (4) and many others.

If we call this general model $\mathcal{M}(p)$, and we assume something about the prior probability of these models (the most natural assumption would be that each $p$ is equally likely) we can compute the probability of the observations given $\mathcal{M}(p)$ for every $p$ and find the best fitting $p$, as Hagen von Eitzen wrote.

If you don't want to assume $\mathcal{M}(p)$, you can assume any other family of models, such as

$\mathcal{M}(p,q)=$*"Mr. Smith comes on even days with probability $p$ and on odd days with probability $q$, independently of other days."*

or

$\mathcal{M}^\prime(p,q)=$*"Mr. Smith comes each with probability $p$ if he visited the day before and with probability $q$ if he didn't"*

Alternatively you can make different assumptions about the distribution of the parameter $p$ in $\mathcal{M}(p)$ - for example, you can say that $p$ must be either $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{2}{3}$ where $\frac{1}{2}$ is twice as likely as the others, or that $p$ follows the normal distribution, or any other assumption.

The process of thinking of such model families and finding the parameters under which they best fit the observations is the key part of many experimental scientific methods.

Comment: Thanks Alfonso. Will try to set up a model. If the model works, I can get myself out of the house before the salesman knocks.

Answer (score 1):

If he knocks everyday with a certain probability $p$ and the events are independant then our obvious estimation for $p$ based on the given sample would be $p=\frac9{30}=\frac3{10}$.
This is also the maximum-likelihood estimation ifwe assume a priori that $p$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$: The probability for $9$ successes among $30$ Bernoulli experiments is ${30\choose 9}p^9(1-p)^{21}$ is maximal if $p=\frac3{10}$.

Comment: Thanks Hagen. Will look into it. If calculation works, yipee! I can escape this salesman.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard answer to this question.

It's not clear what assumption we may make on the randomness of the salesman. Some quite unrealistic, yet non totally stupid assumption would be that on each day, he independently decides to come with a fixed probability $\lambda$. Still, to make this a hard mathematical question, we would need some assumption on the probability distribution of the $\lambda$'s.

As an approximation, since he came on $9$ days out of $30$, lets assume $\lambda = 9/30$. Then this is the chance that he comes on $31$th.

Disclaimer for the case this is some trick question: Factor in the probability that the month actually has $31$ days.

Comment: Thanks Azimut. I'll try your method too. But I reckon there's more to it than just taking 9/30.

Comment: Alex: You're welcome. Basically, my point is the same as in the answer of Alfonso Fernandez: We are lacking a model on the randomness of the salesman. Thus we can only guess the "mechanics" behind the decision if he visits you or not.